# No me reconoce todas las etiquetas HTML en Laravel con {!! $variable !!}

Tags: html, laravel, blade

En la base de datos tengo un texto con etiquetas HTML, por ejemplo:

`<p>, <strong>, <ol>, <ul>, <li>, <blockquote>`

Sí procesa las etiquetas `p` o `strong` pero no las otras.

No sé si en las nuevas actualizaciones haya que configurar algo.
Ya he intentado usar `{!!  !!}` pero sigue con el mismo problema.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.